# Eliminar file de un drive sin usar la API de google drive?

Tags: python, archivo, google-drive

Estoy intentando eliminar un archivo xls de un google drive que tengo descargado en mi computadora. Hasta ahora no tuve problema para sobreescribirlo, pero no me reconoce la ruta cuando intento eliminarlo. Probé los siguientes códigos:

> ```
> ubicacion = "G:\Mi unidad\carpeta_1\carpeta_2\archivo_eliminar.xls"
> try:
>     shutil.rmtree(ubicacion)
> except OSError as e:
>     print(f"Error:{ e.strerror}")
> ```

> `os.rmdir(ubicacion)`

y también:

> `remove('ubicacion')`

Ninguno funciona. Alguna idea de por que o como puede hacerse?

Comment: ¿Y qué error te arroja?

Comment: Prueba a poner una `r` delante de la cadena que contiene la ruta. Es decir `ubicacion = r"G:\Mi unidad\...etc"`

Comment: Ni siquiera me da error, el código se ejecuta bien pero no borra nada. Solo me dice que no se encuentra la ruta especificada si lo especifico en el else. Probé la r también y tampoco funciona